# Django template doesn't display dictionary elements

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-templates

I have a dictionary named Rooms. I am sending the dictionary elements to home.html

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

rooms = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'Lets learn Python!'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Front-End Developer'},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'Back-End Developer '},    
]

def home(request):
    context = {'rooms': rooms}
    return render(request, 'base/home.html', context)

def rooms(request, pk):
    room = None
    for i in rooms:
        if i['id'] == int(pk):
            room = i
    context = {'room': room}
    return render(request, 'base/room.html', context)
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Home Template</h1>

<div>
    <div>
        {% for room in rooms %}
            <div>
                <h5>{{room.id}} -- <a href="/room/{{room.id}}">{{room.name}}</a></h5>
            </div>
        {% endfor %} 
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Home.html displays `<h5>` text but does not display the dictionary elements.I have tried renaming `context` variable.

Comment: Show your url patterns and the url that you are trying to access.

Comment: the id in your dictionary is 'id' a string, but it's value are integers

Comment: @DanielBen-Shabtay The tutorial did the same thing and it worked. I think it dictionary works that way [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtQiiknWUcI&t=3630s)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat `from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="Home"),
    path('room/', views.rooms, name="Rooms"),
]
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that rooms(dict) and rooms(func) was colliding. I just renamed the func to room!

**Updated Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

rooms = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'Lets learn Python!'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Front-End Developer'},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'Back-End Developer '},    
]

def home(request):
    context = {'rooms': rooms}
    return render(request, 'base/home.html', context)

def room(request, pk):
    room = None
    for i in rooms:
        if i['id'] == int(pk):
            room = i
    context = {'room': room}
    return render(request, 'base/room.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this bad boy `room/<int:pk>/` in your `urlpatterns`

```
    from django.urls import path 
    from . import views  
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.home, name="Home"),
        path('room/<int:pk>/', views.rooms, name="Rooms")
    ]
```

Comment: This was added later in the tutorial. This was used to call the `id`. 
I cannot display the dictionary values in home.url

Comment: try rendering `{{ rooms }}` and paste the output in the question.

Comment: I just named both func and dict variable with same name. This confused Django